# How to solve cy.type() failed because it targeted a disabled element

Tags: cypress, chakra-ui, cypress-custom-commands

I am accessing my Gmail account by command loginByGoogleApi under commands.js, then getting the requested email body and pulling the required data from the body, and saving it in a const variable code typing the pulled email data (code) in my testFile.cy.js.
I am able to login after this but cypress throwing me an error ***cy.type() failed because it targeted a disabled element.***

commands.js

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" 
import { parseString } from "xml2js";
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByGoogleApi', () => {  
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    body: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id:  Cypress.env('googleClientId'),
      client_secret:  Cypress.env('googleClientSecret'),
      refresh_token:  Cypress.env('googleRefreshToken'),
    },   
  }).then(({ body }) => {
    const { access_token, id_token } = body
    cy.log('Opening emails including code to verify')
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/verifyCode',
      headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${access_token} },
    }).then(({ body }) => {
      parseString(body, function (err, results) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(results)
        let codeTitle = JSON.parse(data).feed.entry[0].title[0];
        let code = codeTitle.replace('Chaine confirmation code: ','');
        cy.log(code)
      });
    });   
  })
})
```

testFile.cy.js

```js
const { Code } = require("@chaine/keychaine");


describe('Open login page', () => {   
  it('Enter your email to login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://chaineapp.com/staging/login%27)
    cy.get('#field-1').click().type('paras@loadtap.com');
    cy.get('[class*="chakra-button css-yg51i0"]').click();
    cy.get('#pin-input-2-0').type(<need to put code here>);
    })   
  it('get code', () => {
    cy.loginByGoogleApi()

  }) 
})
```

CypressError

> cy.type() failed because it targeted a disabled element.
>
> The element typed into was:

```html
<input aria-label="Please enter your pin code" inputmode="numeric" type="tel" id="pin-input-2-5" autocomplete="one-time-code" placeholder="" class="chakra-pin-input css-jyb0wy" value="1" data-index="5" disabled="">
```

> Ensure the element does not have an attribute named disabled before typing into it.

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9mCz.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `force: true` with `type` to disable actionability checks -

```js
cy.get('#pin-input-2-0').type('text to type', {force: true});
```

Comment: Thanks again Alapan for helping this worked for me.

Comment: This works fine for me in Cypress 10.11